# Assigning different values to multiple variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have around 15 variables to be assigned different values.

```
var1 = val1
var2 = val2
#.....and, so on
```

Should I declare them one by one, or by using a `for` loop?

Is there an inefficiency induced through a `for` loop, considering that looping increases time complexity only if variables are too many. I have only 15.

Reason for asking - I need to do this on several places for different set of variables, on the same code file. Just want to know a preferable way.

Comment: I'd say use loops if possible, will keep your code neat and readable.

Comment: the way you're doing it is fine. so is `var1, var2 = val1, val2`

Comment: How *would* you do that with a loop?

Comment: You should use a list or dictionary based on the use-case.

Comment: Looping doesn't necessarily increase time complexity. Here's a constant time loop : `for x in range(1000): print(x)`

Comment: @pault:  Followed your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : You are right, single loop with single power of `x` == constant time. I did `for x in range(100000000): print x` and my computer froze, lmao! Had to wait for it, as I couldn't shut the pc because of unsaved code-file, it however didn't finish, somehow I got to save my files.

Comment: @lmao on Python 2, you should use `xrange(100000000)`, or better yet, use Python 3

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : Wow `xrange(100000000)` is really fast, thanks for the nice tip.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do this:

```
[var1, var2, var3, ...] = [val1, val2, val3, ...];
```

you can also do this without the lists but this could be used for things like:

```
[var1, var2, var3] = [x**2 for x in range(1,5)]
```

to assign for example to this new variables the squares of 2, 3, 4.

Comment: There's no need for lists at all (in addition to being unnecessary, it's also wasteful), even in the second case (which by the way gives a `ValueError`). If you wanted the squares, a better way would be to use a generator: `var1, var2, var3 = (x**2 for x in range(1,4))`